# proof of Division Algorithm using well ordering principle.

Tags: algorithms

Let $a,b,z_1,z_2  \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $a>0$ and $z_1-z_2=a-1$. Prove that there is a unique $r$ and $q$ with $b=aq+r$ and $z_1≤r≤z_2$.

How can we prove $S$ is not an empty set, $S=\{b-aq\;|\;q\in\mathbb{Z}, b=aq\ge z_1\}$?

And how can prove $r$ and $q$ are unique?

Comment: What is "r"? What set is $r$ in? $q$?

Comment: @Jossie I think you can safely assume that $q$ is the *quotient* and $r$ is the *remainder*, when $b$ is divided by $a$.

Comment: Let $a = 0$. Then $S$ is nonempty.

Comment: Might I suggest your setup be to start with a theorem: Let $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $a>0$. Then there exist unique $q,r \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $b=aq+r$, and $0 \leq r < a$. We can then prove the existence of $S=\{ b-aq \, | \, q \in \mathbb{Z} \wedge b-aq \geq 0 \}$. This would correspond more closely with my understanding (and probably most others) of the theorem you mention, and the portion of the proof that you actually desire.

Answer (score 1):

Let $q=-(|b|+|z_1|)$. Then $b-aq=b+a|b|+a|z_1|\ge z_1$.